# Difference between accessorIterator, iterator and methodIterator

Tags: iterator, oracle-adf

I'm new to ADF BC and I'm trying to add an accessorIterator to my bindings.

However, I'm getting the following error message:

[image]

I'd like to know what's the difference between Accessor Iterator, Method Iterator and Iterator. I've been reading lots of documentation on ADF BC and I can't seem to find any explanation on the different iterators.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kinda self-explanatory.

Quoting documentation:

> Iterator: Iterates over the data items of a collection.
>
> Method iterator: Iterates the results returned from a method. A method
>   iterator is always related to a method action binding, which creates
>   the binding to the actual method to be invoked. The method action
>   binding is what encapsulates the details about how to invoke the
>   method and what parameters (if any) the method is expecting. The
>   method iterator binding handles iterating over the return from that
>   method.
>
> Accessor iterator: Iterates over detail collections returned by
>   accessor methods. Accessor iterators are always related to a master
>   iterator, which is a method iterator. The accessor iterator returns
>   the detail objects related to the current object in the master (or
>   method) iterator

In most cases you need Iterator to work with your bc's data.

Answer (score 0):

**accessorIterator :** Access the accessor of ViewObjects.

**iterator :** Access the ViewObject.

**methodIterator :** Access the custom methods of viewObject.